# Notepad++ Custom Language Highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I have a specific language (its private, and closed source) that I'm writing code highlighting for in Notepad++. I've never done anything like this before... so, for the most part, I'm clueless.

There are a bunch of keywords, and I've figured out how to implement those, but the strings are denoted by square brackets (`[` and `]`) instead of normal quotes. How do I register those as strings in the XML file?

Another thing, the language relies heavily on recursion and nesting; is there some way to say "Level 1 of the square brackets is this color, level 2 is this color, etc..."?

Comment: I don't know about the xml spec but you can specify that under view->user define dialog; boundary open/close

Comment: Did you check out [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/40876/assigning-custom-extensions-to-a-languages-syntax-highlighting-in-notepad)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a useful [help page](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/user-defined-language-system/) that explains how to use the GUI to define a custom language for Notepad++. As Alex K noted in a comment above, the option for setting string delimiters appears to be in the **Delimiters** boxes in the **Operators** tab. It doesn't look like it supports different colours for different levels of nesting, though.

Comment: The Notepad++ wiki seems to have disappeared. [How to create your own definition (user-defined language) of a Syntax Highlighting scheme](https://web.archive.org/web/20130518084439/http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages) on Archive.org

Comment: Thanks @Virtlink -- I've updated the link to use your version.

Comment: Current links are available from [Notepad++ homepage](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/) / [Resources](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/resources.html), [wiki](http://npp-wiki.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files)

Comment: @Betlista That wiki link is dead too now, this one works for now: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Languages

Comment: Currently, it's here: https://ivan-radic.github.io/udl-documentation/

Answer (score 4):

Update for those who have been asking the same question:

(Temporary) Documentation for custom syntax highlighting is on: http://udl20.weebly.com/index.html

There is a link to this in Notepad++ but it doesn't stand out.

Answer (score 2):

I had log4net files that I wanted to view in Notepad++. They contained lines like:

```
2015-06-03 16:38:10,751 [Compname][Thread:29][FATAL]
```

To highlight [FATAL] just the keyword list wasn't enough. I added this:
On tabpage "Folder & Default" > Folding in code style 1: >

```
Open: [ 
Close: ]
```

On tabpage "Keyword lists" > 1ste group > FATAL with some styling.

Comment: folding is for folding the lines of code. To set the delimiter for strings (like `"`, `'`) use delimiter field instead