# How to highlight tpl file?

Tags: smarty, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I'm using NOTPAD++ and I wonder how I can highlight codes in tpl files.

I googled online and there are answers but none of them works. For intance, http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331753/thread/3067a53d/

Any ideas?

Or any other better programmes than NOTEPAD++ for highlighting codes in tpl files?

Answer (score 10):

The following method is compatible with Sublime Text 2 and 3.

1. Open your **.tpl** file in Sublime Text
2. In the **Sublime Text** menu, navigate to **Preferences** → **Package Control**
3. From the drop-down list choose **Package Control: Install Package**
4. Type "**smarty**" and **Sublime Text Smarty** should appear in the search results. Click it to install.
5. In the menu you can now navigate to **View** → **Syntax** → **Smarty** to enable Smarty syntax highlighting for your document.

More information about this package can be viewed [here](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Smarty).

If you end up with the Command Palette (the drop-down part of the UI) still open after installing the package, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>, or on Mac <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>, to toggle it closed again.

Answer (score 9):

I found these instructions and worked for me.

http://was955.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/how-to-add-a-tpl-files-to-notepad-as-a-php-file/

- Step 1) Run Notepad++ using from “Run as Administrator”.
- Step 2) Go to “Settings”->”Style Configurator”.
- Step 3) Add in the .tpl extension name into the “User ext” column by choosing PHP or html as a Language on from the options on left hand selection box.
- Step 4) Click Save & Close on next.

Comment: selecting php would be more adequate, because includes html and php. Selecting html includes only html.

Answer (score 7):

How about `userDefineLang_smarty.xml`:

http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/userDefineLang_smarty.xml

Comment: Please, refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677962/notepad-custom-language-highlighting
;)

Answer (score 2):

My search for a good and free Smarty Editor, resulted in Netbeans with a Smarty Plugin (named PHP Smarty Framework). I am an eclipse user, whenever I need to work on views (templates) I switch to Netbeans. But, I accept this as a Temporary solution and looking for a working smarty plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

SynWrite editor, also free, allows you to create TPL lexer of any kind. See lexer-related tutorials in Readme folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried, the highliting dont seems to work properly (text in white, bg in black).

is it working for you?